# how i to get previous event target in java script

Tags: javascript, html

its my codes
now i wanna to know that how i can check previous target click event and compare with new event
and if both of the event was the equal then,it have be run a command

```
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    let check = evt.target.id; // clicked element
    if(check){
    switch(check) {
        case 'sp':
            var tc = 'tabOne';
            break;
        case 'bp':
            var tc = 'tabTwo';
            break;
        default :
            var tc = 'none';
            break;
    }
    }
    do {
        if (
        tc != 'none'
        ) {
            var tab = document.getElementById(tc)
            tab.classList.toggle('vis')
            return;
        }
        check = check.parentNode;
    } while (check);
});
```

Comment: save it in a global

Comment: @JaromandaX Why should OP polute the global scope with that information? The proper way would be to use a closure (IIFE, class, ...). Or add a "marker" on the clicked element, and before that check if there's already an element with such a marker and if it is the same as the clicked one, or ...

Comment: @Andreas - sure, save it in an IIFE works - didn't want to confuse OP - already uses global `tc` so ... pollution isn't an issue for them

Comment: Why is there a `do ... while` loop when the only thing that changes is not relevant for the actual execution? The event handler could be replaced with: `(evt) => { const mappings = { "sp": "tabOne", "bp": "tabTwo" }; const tab = document.getElementById(mappings[evt.target.id]); if (tab) { tab.classList.toggle("vis"); } }`

Comment: @JaromandaX _"already uses global `tc`"_ - `tc` is only available in the event handler: `var tc = 'tabOne', ...`

Comment: @Andreas - oh, lol ... I don't look for `var` declarations in the wrong place like that :p clearly if the code is written that way, a global isn't going to make the code any worse :p

Comment: @JaromandaX tnx u, resolved my problem with your helps

Comment: @Andreas  tnx u, resolved my problem with your helps